# Store pandas DataFrame in PyTables table without storing index

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

In many `DataFrame.to_foo` functions I can specify that I don't want to write the index

```
>>> help(df.to_csv)

Write DataFrame to a comma-separated values (csv) file

Parameters
----------
...
index : boolean, default True
    Write row names (index)
...
```

Does similar functionality exist for `DataFrame.to_hdf`?  I would like to not store the index in the PyTables table.

Comment: this is not implemented as an option; I suppose it could be but you almost always need it anyhow

Answer (score 1):

You could call out to h5py and interact with HDF5 directly.

```
data = df.values
with h5py.File('data.h5','w') as f:
    f.create_dataset('my_table', data=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppressing index is not out of the box with Pandas.  The issue is tracked at

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8319